# HTML 5 Canvas. How to rotate (keep rotating) only one object (of >1)?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to get a handle on rotating in canvas and I have not found an answer to my issue.

One square is to remain still. Another square to rotate at a specified point. I can either get the entire canvas to rotate at that point, or neither at all. But I cannot get one square to be static and one to rotate.

Please view my codepen demo here: http://codepen.io/richardk70/pen/EZWMXx

The javascript:

```
HEIGHT = 400;
WIDTH = 400;

function draw(){

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

// draw black square
ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();  
ctx.fillRect(75,75,100,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.restore();

// attempt to rotate small, maroon square only
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(225,225);

// small maroon square
ctx.fillStyle = "maroon";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(-25,-25,50,50);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.rotate(.1);
ctx.translate(-225,-225);

// comment out below line to spin
// ctx.restore();

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

I know I could do layered canvases, but surely it can be done in just one canvas layer? Isn't the clock in this tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) doing exactly that?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: If you look at the example you link, it adjusts the amount of rotation based on the current time so each draw call shifts the planets slightly.  You are attempting to accumulate the rotation in the context and that isn't how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate only one image or rendering you need to restore the canvas transform state back to the default.

This function will render your object rotated scaled and translated but not affect any other rendering.

BTW you don't need to use beginPath is the render calls start with fill or stroke such as `ctx.fillRect`, `ctx.strokeRect`, `ctx.fillText`, `ctx.strokeText` and you only need to use `ctx.closePath` if you need to create a line from the last path point to the previous `ctx.moveTo` point or first pathpoint after a `ctx.beginPath` call

Nor do you need to use save and restore for all rendering. You only use it if you need to get the previous canvas state back.

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBox(col,size,x,y,scale,rot){
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    // use setTransform as it overwrites the canvas transform rather than multiply it as the other transform functions do
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.fillRect(-size / 2,-size / 2, size, size);  
}


function update(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,512,256)
    drawBox("black",100,125,125,1,0); // draw none rotated box
    drawBox("maroon",50,225,125,1,time / 500); // draw rotating box
    drawBox("green",25,275,100,1,-time / 250); // draw rotating box
    drawBox("green",25,275,150,1,-time / 250); // draw rotating box
    // after using transforms you need to reset the transform to the default
    // if you plan to render anything in the default coordinate system
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0 ,0 , 1, 0, 0); // reset to default transform

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Blindman, I know I'm not supposed to say "thanks", but I am going to anwyay. I really appreciate your answer with the example solution. Thanks so much.